# Logic App Standard with ASEV3 - what is the price for managed connectors?

Tags: azure-logic-app-standard, azure-cost-calculation

According to the documentation, when we have an ASEV3, we only pay for the App Service Plan and it includes everything, in particular, because managed connectors are executed inside the App Service Environment itself.
This is explained in this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing#standard-single-tenant
And in this particular phrase:

> "When you create or deploy logic apps with the Logic App (Standard)
> resource type, you can use the Workflow Standard hosting plan in all
> Azure regions. You also have the option to select an existing App
> Service Environment v3 resource as your deployment location, but you
> can only use the App Service plan with this option. If you choose this
> option, you're charged for the instances used by the App Service plan
> and for running your logic app workflows. No other charges apply."

But, when I look into the cost analysis of one of my Logic App (deployed in an ASEv3), I can see the cost of the App Service Plan (WS1 in my use case), but also the cost of a "Log Analytics connector" I use in it (resource type is "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS").

Maybe this is a misunderstanding regarding managed connectors that are billed even if they are executed inside the ASEv3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @David GROSPELIER - With the ASEv3 hosting option, while the operations from built-in connectors are *free* for unlimited calls, the operations from managed connectors are metered and billed.

[Doc states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing#standard-single-tenant) the following in the summary table:

> *If your workflow uses any managed connector operations, metering for those operations applies to each call, while billing follows the same Standard or Enterprise connector pricing as the Consumption plan.*

Comment: This post is not very clear: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare

In the table where all Logic App SKUs are compared, it is stated "Pay only for the ASE App Service plan, no matter the number of logic apps that you create and run.". Maybe it should be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

WS1 is not an ASEv3 plan, so you will be charged for the Managed Connectors' executions.